# Sql order by string and int

Tags: sql, sql-order-by

I have table with column days, this days value is like this:

```
day 1
day 2
day 3
day 4
...
day n
```

In my database these row are not ordered, so i want to retrieve it ordered by the int after the string:
example i have

```
day 2
day 4
day 1
day 3
```

=> to got

```
day 1
day 2
day 3
day 4
```

Changing column type and value is the best option but i want to work with this structure if there is an option to retrieve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The orderby clause can use the col and  a right function in order.

```
select * from tablename order by right(day,2) asc
```

Hopping the days got from 1 to max 99 ... if more maybe looking at the space between the day and the number could be another way.

Comment: There is no conversion to a number in this query and the sorting result will be different in another database @Michel Gisenaël

Answer (score 0):

should work:

```
select * from orderby  order by day asc
```

Edit:

Sorry I didn't notice that its string + int:

Fixed my code:

```
select * from orderby order by convert(int, replace(sdate, 'day ', '')) asc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select a, CAST(substring(a from '\d+$') as int) Num from test_tbale order by Num;
```

result

```
 Day 0 | 0
 Day 1 | 1
 Day 3 | 3
 Day 4 | 4
 Day 5 | 5
 Day 7 | 7
```

current data

```
select * from test_table;
   a
-------
 Day 3
 Day 4
 Day 5
 Day 7
 Day 0
 Day 1
```

Postgres

same result using split_part

```
select a, split_part(a , ' ', 2)::int Num from test_table order by Num;

   a   | num
-------+-----
 Day 0 | 0
 Day 1 | 1
 Day 3 | 3
 Day 4 | 4
 Day 5 | 5
 Day 7 | 7
```

complete example

```
create table test_table(a text);
insert into test_table select 'Day ' || floor(random()*100 +1)::text from generate_series(1,10);

select * from test_table;
   a
--------
 Day 19
 Day 87
 Day 86
 Day 34
 Day 50
 Day 97
 Day 84
 Day 81
 Day 67
 Day 6


select a, CAST(substring(a from '\d+$') as int) Num from test_table order by Num;
   a    | num
--------+-----
 Day 6  |   6
 Day 19 |  19
 Day 34 |  34
 Day 50 |  50
 Day 67 |  67
 Day 81 |  81
 Day 84 |  84
 Day 86 |  86
 Day 87 |  87
 Day 97 |  97
```

for MySql 8

```
select a ,CAST(REGEXP_SUBSTR(a, '[0-9]+$') as UNSIGNED) Num from test_table order by Num;
```

MySql without REGEXP_SUBSTR

```
select a ,CAST(SUBSTRING(a, 4) as UNSIGNED) Num from test_table order by Num;
```

Comment: is there an equivalence for mysql?

Comment: For MySQL `select CAST(REGEXP_SUBSTR('Day 24', '[0-9]+$') as UNSIGNED) Num;`

Comment: i added few queries for MySQl